# Можно ли в существующий статичный сайт прикрутить админку?

Tags: html, веб-программирование, сервер

Доброго, есть сайт типа лендинг состоящий из одной страницы, каждая секция сайта хранится в своем хтмл-файле и потом собирается динамически для каждого пользователя(сейчас через html imports, в будущем планируем сделать через gulp). есть ли какой-то способ на существующий сайт прикрутить админку так чтобы заказчик сайта мог зайти и поменять какой-то контент типа текста и видео которые есть на сайте? серверный язык можно любой, лишь бы его можно было поставить на хостинг

Comment: CMS в руки и админка у вас

Comment: Можно всё. Как говорится: любой каприз за ваши деньги

Comment: Опишите, в чём вы видите проблему.

Comment: wix или чуть посложнее - wordpress

Comment: Посмотрите на [Textolite](http://textolite.ru/)

Answer (score 2):

если весь ваш контент хранится  в html-файлах, то вы можете

- дать заказчику доступ через sftp - пусть редактирует руками.
- написать несложную админку, закрытую паролем и https, которая позволит менять определенные поля в этих html-файлах
- написать внутренний сервис (ту же админку, но доступную от вас, извне) который будет принимать изменения для определенных полей и перегенирировать сайт на хостинге.
- взять любой генератор статических сайтов и отдать доступ заказчику (опция один, только сбоку)
- отказаться от этой практики и взять cms/фрэймворк на php/python/node, нанять бэкэндеров. Другое дело, что для лэндинга это не особо нужно, а в некоторых случаях генерация статичных сайтов - вопрос безопасности/быстродействия

на сервер вы можете поставить любой язык, совместимый с вашей операционной системой. В принципе, если сервер принадлежит вам, вы можете хоть Visual Basic 6 в виртуальной машине использовать для генерации контента (это будет очень глупо, конечно)